# Color Changing in Terminal. Specifically my input

Tags: command-line

I want to change the colours in my Terminal and a cursory Google search shows me to right click in terminal and go to properties, etc.

So I managed to change my background, and the text, but I was wondering if I can have what I type be one colour and the system prompts be a different colour?

[image]

Ubuntu 14.04. Running it as a VM on a host Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

For changing the background (and text) colours, you simply go to profile preferences and set it there:

[image]

For the prompt itself, this is set in the prompt itself, this is more complex. This is set from the `~/.bashrc` hidden file (or another similar file), probably using a line like this (it will begin with `PS1`):

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;34m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;32m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

The colour in the prompt is set using [escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (if the terminal being used supports it)- so basically each bit of `\033[Nm` sets the format for the following text, depending on what `N` (`N` can be multiple things separated by `;` BTW).

For the basic colours, you can use the simple numeric codes listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics):
[image]
<sup>1 Makes stuff bold, 0 resets - multiple things can be used as well - e.g:</sup>

```
echo -e "\033[1;32mExample\033[0m"
```

Otherwise you can set your own colour (probably limited support):

```
echo -e "\033[38;2;240;115;0mOrange\033[0m"
```

So you can fairly easily edit the PS1 line to suit (and test it with `echo -e ...`). I recently did this with various colours for different machines so I could use multiple terminals without typing the right command into the wrong computer...